# How to bulk load CRM custom entities

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm using CRM 2013 and I would like to return a large number of custom entities (around 100) based on values in a list.

I can't do `context.MyCustomEntity.Where(i=>list.Contains(i.Id));`

I can't use `RetrieveMultiple` since I want to update these entities and send them back to the server.

So I'm forced to call `context.MyCustomEntity.Where(i=>i.Id == id)` in a loop.

Is there somewhere to prefetch the entities from the context? Or call execute on the where clause in a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the Id's and you don't need to reference any existing dynamic values on the records, you can just update the records. Here's an example:

```
var toUpdate = new MyCustomEntity{Id=id};
// update appropriate values
orgService.Update(toUpdate);
```

However, if you do need to update the fields dynamically, you could chunk the retrievals by using PredicateBuilder to do a dynamic OR condition, but you are limited on the number of criteria you can add to your query. Let me know if this is a path you need to go down, and I can provide more guidance.